# Low batch Batchrequests/sec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, delete

I am running this query to do massive deletion in my database. 
I am looking at Batchrequests/sec and it is quite low (like 15% of what my server can handle)
Is there any way to rewrite this query to do more batchrequest/sec?

```
delete from Position 
Where MainFirmID = 26 and BatchID in (
       select BatchId from MyDB..Batch Where FirmId = 26
              and PeriodId <= 110 and PeriodId > 90
)
```

Thanks for your help.

- RM

Comment: Maybe [batch your deletes a different way](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).